# How can I tell if the server side of a named pipe is an admin?

Tags: windows, security, named-pipes

I am trying to use named pipes on Windows XP SP2+.  The pipe server will be a service, running as some kind of administrator / system level account.  The pipe client could be any user, possibly a guest, possibly an admin.  In my case, I am fine with having a guest account successfully communicate with my service running as administrator.

Before I start using the pipe in my client code, I want to validate that the other side of the pipe is really owned by an administrator / the system.

I have discovered the GetSecurityInfo function, and I think I should be able to use that as part of the solution.  However, I don't know how to get from a SID to an "is admin" check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default owner for all objects created by an administrative account (including the system account) is the well-known Administrators group, and you can't assign ownership of an object you create to someone else without administrative privilege.

So you can check as follows:

- Use [GetSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to fetch the SID of the owner of the pipe object.
- Use [CreateWellKnownSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid option to create a SID for the Administrators group.
- Use [EqualSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to compare the two SIDs.

Make sure that when you open the pipe (using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) you pass the SECURITY_IDENTIFICATION flag to ensure that the potentially malicious server cannot impersonate you.

Comment: This statement sounds very useful, do you know of a place where it is documented?  "The default owner for all objects created by an administrative account (including the system account) is the well-known Administrators group"  Also, thanks for the impersonation tip.

Comment: All I can find is this fairly old article, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126629 ; however, if you're concerned, you could always use SetSecurityInfo to explicitly assign the Administrators group as the owner.

Comment: I guess I could also set it in the initial call to CreateNamedPipe via the lpSecurityAttributes parameter.  That looks like the way to extend this beyond the Administrators group... set the owner and/or primary group to a specific SID, and check for that SID on the client side.  Marking as the answer, but will test it in the next few days.

Comment: The disadvantage of using lpSecurityAttributes is that it means you have to explicitly construct the DACL.  Of course you may wish to do this anyway if the default DACL isn't suitable.  Note that you can't assign an arbitrary SID without first enabling restore privilege and that (if I remember correctly) the Administrators group is a special case; no other group can be assigned as the owner, except by using restore privilege to override the usual rules.